# Open image location from textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have openfiledialog that reading user image address with file info and load it in textbox

I want to have another button in order to open image address (that already saved in textbox)

how to code this button at wpf ? I know i should use process.start but no idea !

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
tbl_Moshtari tt = new tbl_Moshtari();

dlg.FileName = "pic-file-name"; // Default file name 
dlg.DefaultExt = ".jpg"; // Default file extension 
dlg.Filter = "JPEG(.jpeg)|*.jpeg | PNG(.png)|*.png | JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif"; // Filter files by extension 

Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

if (result == true)
{
    ////   picbox.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(dlg.FileName, UriKind.Absolute));
    //bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    //bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    //bitmapImage.StreamSource = System.IO.File.OpenRead(dlg.FileName);
    //bitmapImage.EndInit();
    ////now, the Position of the StreamSource is not in the begin of the stream.
    //picbox.Source = bitmapImage;
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(dlg.FileName);
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
    txt_picaddress.Text = filename;

    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Successfully done");
}
```

This second button i have

```
private void btn_go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    //FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(dlg.FileName);
    string filename = dlg.FileName; 

    Process.Start(filename);
}
```

This isnt working for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Process.Start()` should open up the image as long as `filename` is **an absolute path** to the file. With that being said, where in your `btn_go_Click` method are you actually opening up the dialog to get the file name? `dlg.FileName` returns an empty string if you don't show the dialog in which case `Process.Start()` fails.

If the file name needs to come from the previous dialog, you shouldn't create a new dialog; instead, change

`Process.Start(filename)`

to

`Process.Start(txt_picaddress.Text)`

Of course, you need to do some input verification to make sure the path is correct (unless the textbox is read-only).

Also, consider setting a breakpoint on `string filename = dlg.FileName;` to make sure it has the correct path to the file if it's still not working.

To open and highlight the file in `Windows Explorer`:

```
string filename = txt_picaddress.Text;

ProcessStartInfo pInfo = 
    new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe", string.Format("/Select, {0}", filename));

Process.Start(pInfo);
```

Comment: thank you for your help . I have an another problem here, this code opening file in image viewer windows i want it to open file location(showing folder and highlight image) like open file location windows 7 .

Answer (score 0):

In your second code sample, you created a new instance of openFileDialog, you need instead to use the previous instance of the openFileDialog that is holding the correct image filename:

if you create the first openFileDialog in the window constructor you can do this:

```
private void btn_go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  

    string filename = this.dlg.FileName; 

    Process.Start(filename);
}
```

hope this helps, this is what  i can say given the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `OpenFileDialog` in `btn_go_Click` if you want to use the path in your textbox:

```
private void btn_go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string filename = txt_picaddress.Text; 
    Process.Start(filename);
}
```